# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property ' activePackage'

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, ireport

I am giving the Fieldname in the ireport as the attribute name in the entity class. But I am getting the following Exception.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'activePackage'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1122)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:686)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:715)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:290)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:895)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:860)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:837)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1434)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:126)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:765)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.fillReport(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:559)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The following is my jrxml code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <field name="activePackage" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[activePackage]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="27" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[activePackage]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="26" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{activePackage}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The below one is my entity class code:

```java
@Entity
@JsonAutoDetect
@Table(name = "ra_bdr_rating")
public class RaBdrRating extends BaseModel {
@Column(name="active_package")
    private String activePackage;
 public String getActivePackage() {
        return activePackage;
    }
 public void setActivePackage(String activePackage) {
        this.activePackage = activePackage;
    }
}
```

This is the code in my controller class

```
public ModelAndView generateHtmlReport(@ModelAttribute("reports") RaReports     model,ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception{

    Map<String,Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    List<RaBdrRating> packagesList = reportsDao.retrieveAllPackages(model);

    JRDataSource JRdataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(packagesList);

    parameterMap.put("datasource", JRdataSource);

    //htmlReport bean has ben declared in the jasper-views.xml file
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("htmlReport", parameterMap);

    return modelAndView;

}
```

Here `activePackage` I have declared as private variable of string type in my entity class. So in my jrxml I am giving the same name with `fieldDescription`. If I click on preview in iReport there also I am getting the same problem. I am using ***iReport 4.5.0***.
Here retrieveAllPackages(model) has a jpa query which retrieves all the packages and returning in the form of list of type RaBdrRating.RaBdrRating is my entity class the one i posted earlier.I am passing that list to the JRBeanCollectionDatasource and placing the datasource in the map.Now i want to display the list in my report.So i am designing a report in iReport in such a way that the field name must match with the attribute name in the entity class.I think now you will get some idea on this.

Comment: well, helping people would need your code snippet first. Then a description about your aim and what you tried. Also you should use a debugger and check out the values that your variables get. After that there might be a useful look at this stack trace. What you think?

Comment: Definitely post the relevant excerpt from your .jrxml.

Comment: Is `activePackage` private field? If so, can you try with getter setter methods of it?

Comment: @Vanathi `PropertyUtilsBean` works with JavaBeans and always insists on getters.

Comment: @rupa It this compilation error? Did you get it in iReport? You should post the code of your bean classes

Comment: Yes activePackage is private field in my bean class and i have the setter and getter methods also.I will post the jrxml and my bean class so that it is easy for you to identify the problem.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik,@Vanathi I have posted the code.Can you please check it and give me the reply.I am struggling with this exception from 3 days.I am new to this forums so if anything wrong please excuse me.

Comment: Once you have `$F{activePackage}` and twice just `activePackage`. Just wondering...

Comment: @ Marko Topolnik Thanks for giving the reply.I didnt get what you are telling.If you dontmine can you explain briefly.I am totally new with this ireport,spring.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Can you explain me what is wrong in my code.I have given $F{activePackage} as the textField in my detail band and activePackage as the static text in my columnHeader band.Anything wrong over here.

Comment: And this `RaBdrRating` instance is your model object that you give Jasper? How exactly does that work? Do you have some code you use to create the object?

Comment: Yes.I have given some more information also.You can check it now.

Comment: Hi,Did you get any idea regarding this issue.

Comment: still facing the same problem no reply....

Comment: find out the problem....

Answer (score 3):

Remove the fileDescription from the field

```
<fieldDescription><![CDATA[activePackage]]></fieldDescription>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this "**false**" works for me

```
JRDataSource JRdataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(packagesList, **false**);
```